# Twitter c# client unable to post due to error 417

Tags: c#, twitter, webclient

I'm creating a twitter client without from scratch and on my 64bit machine at home i can post fine no problem, but on my 32bit laptop I'm getting a error 417 when I come to post a tweet.

I am able to read tweets fine, just posting that seems to be a problem I have also put in the following which some people said stop the error from accuring without any luck

```
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

I am unsure what to do next has anyone else got any ideas? the code for posting is below.

thanks matt

```
       string aUrl = "http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml";

        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_username, _password);

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        byte[] tweetBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("status=" + tweet);

        client.UploadData(aUrl,tweetBytes);

        return true;
```

Comment: I know this isn't  your question, but I would look into TweetSharp found here http://tweetsharp.com/

Comment: thanks but wanting to create it all from scratch. Part of a learning curve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at http://github.com/erans/twitter-csharp-library

This snippet was taken from the twitter.cs file on github.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes an HTTP POST command and retrives the information.     
    /// This function will automatically include a "source" parameter if the "Source" property is set.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">The URL to perform the POST operation</param>
    /// <param name="userName">The username to use with the request</param>
    /// <param name="password">The password to use with the request</param>
    /// <param name="data">The data to post</param> 
    /// <returns>The response of the request, or null if we got 404 or nothing.</returns>
    protected string ExecutePostCommand(string url, string userName, string password, string data) {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) {
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Method = "POST";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TwitterClient)) {
                request.Headers.Add("X-Twitter-Client", TwitterClient);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TwitterClientVersion)) {
                request.Headers.Add("X-Twitter-Version", TwitterClientVersion);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TwitterClientUrl)) {
                request.Headers.Add("X-Twitter-URL", TwitterClientUrl);
            }


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Source)) {
                data += "&source=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Source);
            }

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()) {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
                        return reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```